# KnockoutJS with Sammy.js SPA suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, sammy.js

I am building a SPA app with the following structure:

```html
<body>
    <!-- Main Container for our application -->
    <div id="main">

    </div>
    <!-- End Main Container -->

    <!-- Vendor Libraries -->
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/knockout/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/sammy/sammy-latest.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Models -->
    <script src="js/models/model1.js"></script>

    <!-- ViewModels -->
    <script src="js/viewmodels/viewModel1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/viewmodels/viewModel2.js"></script>

    <!-- App scripts -->
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

The html file has a `div` which will hold the html for each respective page handled by Sammy.js wit the following code:

```
Sammy('#main', function() {

    this.get('#/', function(context) {
        context.$element().load('views/main1.html', function() {
            ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel1(), $("#home")[0]);
        });
    });

    this.get('#/text', function(context) {
        context.$element().load('views/text.html', function() {
            ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel2(), $("#home")[0]);
        });

    });

    this.get('', function(context) {
        this.redirect('#/');
    });

}).run();
```

Each time I am loading the markup found in each html file and then apply my viewmodel.

My questions are:

1. Can you suggest any other possible way to load the markup apart from using jquery load().
2. Are my old bindings being disposed each time a new route is being called?

Answer (score 1):

1: This question is very 'open'. There are tons of way to do this that aren't `jquery.load`. But the real question is: do you NEED another way? Do you need some form of control that `$.load` isn't giving you?
If you do, consider switching to `jquery.get` or `jquery.ajax`, and handle the request yourself. At the bottom of this post is an example.

2: No, because you keep applying the bindings to the same element. What you instead want to do is apply bindings to the first element WITHIN the container with id 'home'. Then, when you switch views, you want to do `ko.removeNode` on the view that you're removing. Below is a code example that illustrates how you can gain some more control over the process and clean up your bindings behind you.

```
function loadView(url, viewModel) {
    $.get(url, function (response) {
        var $container = $('#home'),
            $view = $container.find('.view'),
            $newView = $('<div>').addClass('view').html(response);
        if ($view.length) {
            ko.removeNode($view[0]); // Clean up previous view
        }
        $container.append($newView);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $newView[0]);
    });
}
this.get('#/', function(context) {
    loadView('views/main1.html', new ViewModel1());
});
this.get('#/', function(context) {
    loadView('views/text.html', new ViewModel2());
});
```

What I did in this example is using `jquery.get` so we gain control over the whole process of loading and displaying the HTML. I then refactored part of the logic out into a separate function that is generic enough to use on every view you have.
When a view is retrieved I store it in an element with class 'view'. The bindings are applied to this element and it is stored in your container element. When switching views I clean up and remove the old view before the new view is added to the DOM.

This is just the beginning: In the `loadView` function, you can now try to call generic methods that you can implement on your viewmodels, such as 'activate' and 'deactivate'. You can also show a spinner instead of a view when a new view is being retrieved, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Some things are clear now. The $('home')[0] is actually the first element inside each html file I am calling as follows: 
    <div id="home">
        <div data-bind="text: text1"></div>
        <a href="#/">click me now</a>
    </div>
Each time I am adding the above markup into the div with id "main". Thus I presume using your code above I will call removeNode prior of calling the load method.